# Google Datastore API Query Ancestor Filter

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to run a query in Google Datastore using the python API (described [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries)). The model of my data in datastore is I have certain `Location`s, containing a name, latitude, and longitude, and then `WeatherData` objects that contain weather data such as temperature, etc. and a time stamp. Each `WeatherData` has a parent `Location` entity to which it pertains. I am trying to query all of the `WeatherData`s for a given `Location` within a specific time frame. However, when I try to run the ancestor query, I believe it is applying the filters to the ancestor as well, which wouldn't work because `Location` has different fields than `WeatherData`. See my code below:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from datetime import datetime
client = datastore.Client()
dad = client.key('Location','Boston')
query = client.query(kind='WeatherData', ancestor=dad)
start_date = datetime(2018, 1, 20, 0, 0)
end_date = datetime(2018, 1, 21, 0, 0)
query.add_filter('time', '>', start_date)
query.add_filter('time', '<', end_date)
query_iter = query.fetch()
temps = [entity.get('apparentTemperature') for entity in query_iter]
```

I am able to query only with the ancestor, and I am also able to query with no ancestor but with the time filters. I have also tried to run the ancestor query and simply order it by time and not filter it, but it does not work. When I run the above code, it produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 121, in inner
    return to_call(*args)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 68, in inner
    return a_func(*updated_args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 484, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 434, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: WeatherData
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: time
)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_gax.py", line 74, in _catch_remap_gax_error
    yield
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_gax.py", line 134, in run_query
    return super(GAPICDatastoreAPI, self).run_query(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/datastore/v1/datastore_client.py", line 258, in run_query
    return self._run_query(request, options)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 452, in inner
    return api_caller(api_call, this_settings, request)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 438, in base_caller
    return api_call(*args)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 376, in inner
    return a_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 127, in inner
    ' classified as transient', exception)
google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: WeatherData
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: time
)>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 186, in _items_iter
    for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 217, in _page_iter
    page = self._next_page()
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/query.py", line 498, in _next_page
    query=query_pb,
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_gax.py", line 134, in run_query
    return super(GAPICDatastoreAPI, self).run_query(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_gax.py", line 82, in _catch_remap_gax_error
    six.reraise(error_class, new_exc, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_gax.py", line 74, in _catch_remap_gax_error
    yield
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_gax.py", line 134, in run_query
    return super(GAPICDatastoreAPI, self).run_query(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/datastore/v1/datastore_client.py", line 258, in run_query
    return self._run_query(request, options)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 452, in inner
    return api_caller(api_call, this_settings, request)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 438, in base_caller
    return api_call(*args)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 376, in inner
    return a_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andyw/frontend_data/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 127, in inner
    ' classified as transient', exception)
google.api_core.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: 412 no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: WeatherData
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tracebacks have the same root cause:

```
no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: WeatherData
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: time
```

Basically your query requires a composite index (exactly the one included in the message) which was not found in your datastore index configuration. You need to add that index definition to your `index.yaml` configuration file and (re)deploy that file.

From [About index.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_About_index_yaml) (that entire doc page is of interest):

> Every Cloud Datastore query made by an application needs a
>   corresponding index. Indexes for simple queries, such as queries over
>   a single property, are created automatically. Indexes for complex
>   queries must be defined in a configuration file named `index.yaml`.
>   This file is uploaded with the application to create indexes in Cloud
>   Datastore.

Note: while your query *might* appear to be over a single property - `time`, it's not: it's also an ancestor query, the `dad` ancestor couns as an additional property. Hence you query requires a composite index.